# Edit custom field using user_presave hook during account creation

Tags: 7, hooks

I have made a custom field for user `field_custom_xyz` from the admin GUI.
Now after i saved it i got two tables into the database : one for data and one for revisions.
I already have a huge database into which a lot of users are already there.

I have two questions :

1. How can i make sure that i can assign default value to each user at the time of creation of this field?
2. Let's say if i have to assign a default value of `0` (or null in case i don't follow step 1).
   how can i change that value at the time of new registration using  **hook_user_presave** ?

I want to override the default value of this field using `user_presave` hook in some custom module lets say 'abc' module

so far i have tried :

`$account->field_custom_abc['und'][0]['value'] = 0;`

but that doesn't work, any suggestions.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_user_presave().
 */
function mymodule_user_presave(&$edit, $account, $category) {
  $edit['field_custom_xyz'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = 0;
}
```

Comment: Good, glad that help .